# ReactJS where are Mouse events explained?

Tags: reactjs

This page of the docs lists all mouse events, but I can find anywhere what is what https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These aren't React-specific. Any general JavaScript documentation will cover it, for example, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_mouseevent.asp